# GTK-theming: one version for every major or every minor release?

Tags: css, linux, gtk, themes, gtk3

I'm currently working on an GTK-theme, based on Arc-Theme. 
(You can see my current progress here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/100718986567621730640/posts/S6QqGbehjNj)

My knowledge in CSS and GTK-theming is basic, mostly it's just trial and error.
I started from another Arc-fork, called OSX-Arc-Plus (no real reason behind it, it was just the theme I've been using when starting to change things). This themed contained subfolders for various minor-releases. As I'm using elementary OS, I used gtk-3.18. Now I've seen that the original Arc theme contains only one gtk-3 folder.

So thinking of the future with support for more versions, I have no idea, where to go 
a) just releasing one version for every major release (like original Arc-theme)
b) putting some work in and do one version for every minor Gtk-version (like OSC-Arc-Plus, Paper-theme, Pop-theme)

So what's the advantage and disadvantage of these possibilities? I would expect a) to be okay, as Arc is used so much around the Linux world, but Paper and Pop are great themes too, and they use b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.20+ stabilized CSS names and 3.22 will be the last major version in the 3 series so you should focus on that. If you really need to support Ubuntu LTS then you would have to make a 3.18 version of course. I would not suggest targeting anything other than those two.

As for directories in practice it doesn't really matter because people don't install two Gtk3 versions at the same time.

I don't know if that answers your question or not.

Comment: Partly, thank you! So I know, which versions to tackle. But what's the difference between making only one file (for all) and one file per version?

Comment: You can't make one file for all, they have different names and behaviors.

Comment: My bad, I installed Arc from ppa, that's why I only got one GTK3-version! The other ones exist, but didn't get downloaded. That's why I thought he did it with one file only!
Thank you!